# NavigationMixin callback?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a Lightning Web Component that uses NavigationMixin to allow inline object creation of a task:

```
 onClickNewTask(event) {
      let nav = {
          type: 'standard__objectPage',
          attributes: {
              objectApiName: 'Task',
              actionName: 'new'                
          },
          state : {
              defaultFieldValues:"WhatId=" + this.recordId,
              navigationLocation: 'RELATED_LIST'
          }
      };
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](nav);
 }
```

This opens a modal for creating a Task and allows the user to create a task from that modal. Now I want to refresh some data once the user finishes creating that task. Is there a callback/event handler I can attach?

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_basic), The navigation service adds two APIs to your component's class.

1. `[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageReference,[replace])`
2. `[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](pageReference)`

A component calls `this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]` to get a promise that resolves to the resulting URL but you will not get any **promise** by using `[NavigationMixin.Navigate](pageReference,[replace])`